# API call in React is leading to performance issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval

I have created a table of components, where each row of the component, separately calls the backend api, that I have created using express.js after every 5 seconds, as can be seen here.

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import { Td } from "../styled/components";
import axios from 'axios';

function TmfComponent({url, name}) {

    const [status, setStatus] = useState(null);
    const [cacheStatus, setCacheStatus] = useState(null);
    const [appStatus, setAppStatus] = useState(null);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [state, setState] = useState(false);

    console.log("I am rendered again!");

    useEffect(function () {
        const intervalCall = setInterval(() => {
            setState(!state);
            console.log("State is changed");
        }, 5000);
        return () => clearInterval(intervalCall);
    }, [state]);

    function getData() {
        axios.post("http://localhost:8000/health", {
            url, name
        }, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            // console.log(response);
            if (loading) {
                setLoading(false);
            }
            if (response.data.appStatus !== appStatus) {
                setAppStatus(response.data.appStatus);
            }
            if (response.data.status !== status) {
                setStatus(response.data.status);
            }
            if (response.data.cacheStatus !== cacheStatus) {
                setCacheStatus(response.data.cacheStatus);
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
            setAppStatus("Failed");
            setCacheStatus("Failed");
            setStatus("Failed");
        })
    }

    useEffect(function () {
        getData();
    }, [state]);



    // useEffect(function () {
    //     const intervalCall = setInterval(() => getData(), 5000);
    //     return () => clearInterval(intervalCall);
    // }, []);

    // const Td = styled.td`
    //     border: 1px solid #000;
    // `

    const appStatusStyle = {
        backgroundColor: appStatus != null ? (appStatus === "UP" || appStatus === "Healthy" ? "#03DAC6" : "#ff0266") : "#ffeeee"
    };

    const overallStatusStyle = {
        backgroundColor: status != null ? (status === "UP" || status === "Healthy" ? "#03DAC6" : "#ff0266") : "#ffeeee"
    };

    const cacheStatusStyle = {
        backgroundColor: cacheStatus != null ? (cacheStatus === "UP" || cacheStatus === "Healthy" ? "#03DAC6" : "#ff0266") : "#ffeeee"
    };


    return <tr>
        <Td>{name}</Td>
        <Td style={appStatusStyle}> {loading ? "Loading..." : (appStatus ?? "N/A")} </Td>
        <Td style={cacheStatusStyle}> {loading ? "Loading..." : (cacheStatus ?? "N/A")}</Td>
        <Td style={overallStatusStyle}> {loading ? "Loading..." : (status ?? "N/A")}</Td>
    </tr>
}
export default TmfComponent;
```

As you can see here, this component represents a row in the table, which is represented as follows:

```
import TmfComponent from "./TmfComponent";
import shortid from 'shortid';
import PageLoader from "./PageLoader";

export default function  TmfComponentList({tmfRequests}) {

    let displayComponent;
    if (tmfRequests.length > 0) {
        displayComponent = tmfRequests.map((component) => <TmfComponent key={shortid.generate()} name={component.name} url={component.url}/>);
        return <div>
            <table style={{width: "100%"}}>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>API Name</th>
                        <th>App Status</th>
                        <th>Cache Status</th>
                        <th>Overall Status</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {displayComponent}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    } else {
        return <div>
            <PageLoader />
        </div>
    }
}
```

Since I am calling the api for each row every 5 seconds, the components are getting rerendered every 5 seconds. However, after 5 minutes or so I am facing performance issues. Now I know that the result of the response is almost always the same every time. So I am thinking of re-rendering the component only when the result of the response is different from the previous response.

Is there any way in react to make possible? Because I believe that performance issues are happening due to excessive re-rendering of the components.

**Please note:**
I have also tried the useEffect hook, with [] as dependency, which means that it will be called in the first time only, and added the setOnInterval method in that as well, however, there also I am facing performance issues.

If this is not the correct approach, I am open to better approach as well. Thanks!

Comment: If the result of the API response is the same as the previous one, don't call the state setter function.

Comment: Hi! as you can see, I am doing an check and if it is not same then only I am setting it, but, still performance issues are happening. I mean I want to do render only when api response is different from previous one, or anything that is better, since around 50 calls are being made every 5 seconds or so.

Comment: few suggestions, make it event based update, may be webhooks. Is it necessary to call API for each row? can't we convert this usecase into a single API ?

Comment: actually it is not event based, I do need to call it every 5 seconds to check the health of other external api's, also since each row corresponds to different external api as a result, even if I am calling single api, the payload is different as you can see.

Comment: I want to only render the component when the api returns a different response, else not render the row, but useEffect unequivocally, is rendering every 5 seconds or so even if api result is same, is there any other hook or so that can help me out, like caching the response or so?